# SEO - What to do when content is taken offline

Tags: seo

I'm going to have a site where content remains on the site for a period of 15 days and then gets removed.

I don't know too much about SEO, but my concern is about the SEO implications of having "content" indexed by the search engines, and then one day it suddenly goes and leaves a 404.

What is the best thing I can do to cope with content that comes and goes in the most SEO friendly way possible?

Comment: So, you think you'd need to tell the SE that you removed your content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way will be to respond with HTTP Status Code 410;

from w3c:

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be
>   considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD
>   delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the
>   server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not
>   the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be
>   used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web
>   maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is
>   intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that
>   remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for
>   limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to
>   individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not
>   necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or
>   to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the
>   discretion of the server owner.

more about status codes [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: The trouble is with this is that if I user visits the page it isnt very friendly to just show a 401 error page. For the user I would rather show something like "The content you were looking for is no longer available", but I am guessing this is bad for SEO?

Comment: @JamesWillson - if we are talking about what to show to user, - then you can show whatever you want, just don't forget to send it with 410 status code instead of 200;

Answer (score 0):

To keep the traffic it may be an option to not delete but archive the old content. So it remains accessible by its old URL but linked at some deeper points in the archive on your site.

If you really want to delete it then it is totally ok to return with 404 or 410. Spiders understand that the resource is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Most search engines use something called a robot.txt file.  You can specify which URLs and Paths you want the search engine to ignore.  So if all of your content is at www.domain.com/content/* then you can have Google ignore that whole branch of your site.